# Правильно написанный код на Python в PyCharm выдает сообщение об ошибке

Tags: python, pycharm

```
import tkinter as tk


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def _init_(self, root):
        super()._init_(root)


if _name_ == "main":
```

В Windows 11 учетная запись  была "ЮП", в русском регистре. Создал пользователя "jurpal" и создал этот же код, ошибка пропала. Снес систему, установил с учетной записью "JP", опять ошибка. Очевидно какие-то ошибки при установке PyCharm или в процессе создания нового проекта.

Это моя первая попытка изучать Python, нужна программа в которой в таблице нужно выбирать количество необходимых товаров и печатать ее на принтере.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Мне нужно выяснить, причину возникновения ошибки и как ее исправить. Самостоятельно решить не смог.

Comment: Вот копия экрана с ошибкой https://disk.yandex.ru/i/mTjSnQT62r5bKw

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать ваш код в **в текстовом виде** и **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: Поразительно! Первая попытка изучать питон, но уверен, что код написан правильно, а ошибка в установке pycharm. А тебе не пришло в голову, что текст ошибки можно прочитать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Имена `_init_` (дважды в вашем коде) `_name_` и `main` нужно писать с **двумя** знаками подчеркивания, т.е. так:

```
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)

if __name__ == "__main__"
```

Comment: Да и пустое тело `if`, если это весь код, это тоже ошибка.

Comment: Большое спасибо, действительно ошибка была в коде.

Comment: @jurpal, не стоит. :-)